# Meeting organization

Tags: professionalism, behavior

I am a developer who is new to big company environments. I am tasked with writing simulations for our products for testing them. Due to that, I have to frequently get feedback from product developers, especially if its a new line of products.

My question is if I should choose a date and time for a feedback meeting I require or if I should let them pick the date and time most convenient to them. I am generally very flexible in my work so for me it is no problem to reschedule but I am concerned that my simply leaving the decision to them could be seen as rude or lazy.

Also, English is not my first language so sorry if I worded anything unclearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am generally very flexible in my work so for me it is no problem to reschedule but I am concerned that my simply leaving the decision to them could be seen as rude or lazy.

It's not rude or lazy to let someone pick a time that suits them. Just make sure you give them a window to choose from ("can we meet at some point this week" or "are you around at any point Thursday morning" etc.) and see what they say.

If they don't get back to you (some people are just bad at replying), then you can just pick a time, send an invite and ask them to reschedule if inconvenient. Some people seem to work better that way.

Comment: +1. Yes, take the lead on scheduling but let people reschedule at times more convenient to them if need be. That's perfectly polite and professional. (People will let you know if you're pestering them more than they want you to.)

Answer (score 2):

If this is going to be a frequent meeting (eg once a week/month), I would informally discuss availability with the team and set up a regular meeting. This means that everyone can plan for it and it won't catch them by surprise.

If, however, this is not going to be regular meeting, I find that it's best to check everyone's calendar and set up a meeting when everyone is free, and it's not lunchtime (you get better feedback if people aren't annoyed at you).